# Empty msg.sender in contract function when called from Remix testing

Tags: solidity, remix-tests

I have a very simple contract function (bogusFunc) that makes use of the implicit msg.sender:

```
function bogusFunc(uint256 _val) public
{
    // use _val for something
    user_list.push(msg.sender);
}

function isUser(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
    for (uint256 s = 0; s < user_list.length; s += 1){
        if (_address == user_list[s]) return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}
```

Function works fine from truffle console. Now I want to create a unit test from the remix UI:

```
function beforeAll() public {
    // Here should instantiate tested contract
    foo = new Storage();
}

function checkBogus() public {
    foo.bogusFunc(1);
    Assert.equal(foo.isUser(msg.sender), true, "Could not add user");
}
```

When running the test, this fails (isUser(msg.sender) returns false).

Now, if I make the function with explicit msg.sender:

```
function bogusFunc(uint256 _val, address _address)
    public
{
    // use _val for something
    user_list.push(_address);
}
```

And modify the unit test:

```
function checkAdd() public {
    foo.bogusFunc(1, msg.sender);
    Assert.equal(foo.isUser(msg.sender), true, "Could not add user");
}
```

This works fine! It seems like when executing remix testing, the contract function runs without loading values for msg.* ... is there any way to specify that in the tests? or maybe I am overseeing or omitting something?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I found the documentation in the [REMIX-IDE readthedocs](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting_examples.html#testing-a-method-involving-msg-sender) 

Basically you need to do acc0 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(0); when initializing the tests (beforeAll()) and then acc0 becomes msg.sender

Comment: Turns out acc0 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(0); doesn't work either... it gives a different address as msg.sender in the contract ....